# Superscripts in WPF window title

Tags: wpf, xaml, window, title

I need to be able to superscript TM inside the title window of my page.How can i do that in XAML ?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the Unicode trademark symbol, ™, in your window's `Title` attribute:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Super Awesome Main Window™">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol
Short and sweet, use ALT + 0153 if you're using windows, otherwise you could just try and copy/paste '™'.

Have fun coding!

Comment: Bear in mind to punch the number keys on the keypad, not the row of digits above the alphabet row.

Comment: Yep, sorry - didn't think to mention that, glad you got it sorted.